# Preencher input ao clicar em botao e multiplicar valores

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, boa tarde, estou com uma dúvida no seguinte, quero criar um sistema que ao clicar em um botão, gere o valor em um input, isso eu já fiz, porém preciso que, ao clicar mais vezes nesse botão, o valor do input alterar para "Exemplo (1..2..3)", com o valor da multiplicação entre ().
Um exemplo de como ficaria seria o seguinte:

[image: exemplo]

Resumindo, se eu clicasse duas vezes em Adicionar, me retornaria isso, e se eu clicasse uma vez em Remover, seria mudado para "Produto Exemplo (1)".
Muito obrigado a quem puder ajudar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cria variáveis para os elementos dos `input`e os input type `button`, coloca um `addEventListener()` para quando clicar no botão adicionar ele faz uma `function` q adiciona +1 para a variável `produto` e se clicar no botão remover ele faz uma `function` remove -1 da variável `produto`. Coloquei também para que se o a variável `produto` se for menor que 0 sempre ser 0 e nunca negativo, e quando ela for 0 não aparece nada no `input` type `text`. E quando for maior que 0 aparecer "Produto Exemplo ()" e a variável `produto` dentro dos parenteses no input text.

```js
var adicionar = document.getElementById('Adicionar')
var remover = document.getElementById('Remover')
var input = document.getElementById('Exemplo')

var produto = 0

adicionar.addEventListener('click', function(){
    produto++
    
    if (produto > 0) {
   input.value = `Produto Exemplo (${produto})`
   
} else if (produto <= 0) {
    produto = 0
    input.value = ""
}
})

remover.addEventListener('click', function(){
    produto--
    
    if (produto > 0) {
   input.value = `Produto Exemplo (${produto})`
   
} else if (produto <= 0) {
    produto = 0
    input.value = ""
}
})
```

```html
<hr>
<h2>Produto Exemplo </h2>
<input id="Adicionar" type="button" value="Adicionar">
<input id="Remover" type="button" value="Remover">
<br>
<input id="Exemplo" type="text" readonly value="">
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Justamente o que eu precisava, muito obrigado!! E ainda me ajudou com a explicação de como funciona!

Comment: Opa, De nada, 